# How to hide sub-directories in the url with web2py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I am building a website on Google App Engine using web2py but I would like to show only the root domain to visitors. Here is an example to make it clear, if I go to www.domain.com/user, I am actually calling function 'user' in 'default.py'. It is not a static file. Is there any way i can hide anything after the domain to just show www.domain.com?

I tried to mess around with app.yaml and appengine_config.py. It didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
routes_in = (
  ('/user', '/login'),
)

routes_out = (
  ('/user', '/'),
)
```

in `web2py/routes.py`. See [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Pattern-based-system) for more info.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the above in routes.py Now I get 500 internal error. Somewhere wrong?

Comment: you have to restart web2py, if it still doesnt work, try only with the `routes_out` part.

Comment: 500 internal error disappeared after I added a comma in routes_in, but still not working. Neither after I restarted web2py or use routes_out only.

Comment: which version of web2py do you have? Just to check, do you want for example `www.domain.com/abc` and `www.domain.com/xyz` to go into your user function but showing `www.domain.com` in the browser?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want! Im running the latest version of web2py. Im using source code with google app engine sdk to test locally on mac.

Comment: I just figured I wasn't clear on this. I want to type `www.domain.com/user` in the browser and run **user** or `www.domain.com/login` and run **login** in **default.py**, but appear to be www.domain.com in browser. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: ok, I edited the answer, you get the idea, '/user' goes to '/login'(because of the routes_in part), but '/user' shows '/'(because of the routes_out part). Restart web2py and tell me how it goes.

Comment: sorry but this is the opposite of what I want. In your code, `www.domain.com/user` is running `login` but still showing `www.domain.com/user` in the browser. I want `www.domain.com/user` to run `user` and `www.domain.com/login` to run `login` but showing `www.domain.com`. Basically just hide everything coming after the domain.